# Webpack html loader - load background image

Tags: javascript, html, webpack, pug, webpack-html-loader

Im using webpacks html-loader in combination with pug-html-loader, and its working fine for img tags with src attributes.

However if I have a div with an inline `style="background-image: url()"` attribute, the image referenced there is not included/loaded via webpack into the output directory

What is the correct way to ensure that any asset I want to load in my pug template will be processed via webpack?